# Riverpod's basic provider isn't working while using Supabase SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, supabase

This is the code snippet with Supabase SDK

[Code block with Supabase SDK enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr0sg.jpg)

[Code block the Supabase SDK disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUX8w.jpg)

As you can see from the first picture, only the basic provider is having an error "Provider isn't a function, try to define a method or function with the name Provider" whereas other providers are working fine.

If anyone faced a similar issue or know the reason for the issue, please help with this would be really appreciated.

I wasn't even able to trackdown the actual cause of not working of Provider until hours of random testing, disabling every possible cause.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you copy and paste your code instead of attaching screenshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `Provider` enum in supabase_flutter. You can hide it to get rid of the error you are seeing.

```dart
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart' hide Provider;
```